# Modifying the code based on user feedback

Tags: java

I am storing some data in a hash map. Now I want to modify the values associated with a key based on a user input and store them these way permanently.

To make myself more clear, I have a hashmap like this:

```
public static HashMap<String,Integer> mymap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
mymap.put("Hi",2);
mymap.put("Hello",3);
```

I will take feedback from user in some user and if he wants then I will, say, store 4 against Hello. I want these changes to be saved for future references.

I have heard about [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) API in Java, but am not sure whether that will serve the purpose.

Comment: Modifying the code isn't really necessary, is it? You just want to modify the data contained in the map. That's a lot more straightforward than modifying the code.

Comment: I don't follow - are you asking how to store the map to disk? or how to modify the map? `Map.put()` provides just that - it will override the old value.

Comment: Saved where? Memory? File system? Database? For each of these, you wouldn't need reflection anyway!

Comment: isbadawi: Yeah, I want to modify the data contained in the hashmap..

Comment: @adarshr: I am not saving it anywhere. they are a part of my program itself

Comment: to save it permanently, you can use serialization.

Comment: @PrototypeStark: I am not aware about serialization. But will check it out !!

Comment: It sounds like you want a database.

Comment: @NullUserException he might not need a database. His input seems to be much too small to dabble with a full fledged DBMS. He can try SQLITE if he wants to.

Comment: @NullUserException: I dont want to get database into it. Can't I do it this way around ?

Comment: There are many ways to do what you want; depending on the requirements a database *could* be the best answer. Like @PrototypeStark suggested, you can try SQLite if you're dealing with smaller amounts of data.

Comment: @NullUserException: I understand that I can use a database. But here I just dont have enough data to put it into a database. What about serialization ?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. If you serialize it, now you have to write and maintain your serialization and deserialization routines. I generally tend to err on the side of using something that's easy to handle, structured, and well-defined like a database (in this case you can look at SQLite). This is especially true in Java, where serialization isn't nearly as easy to use and straightforward as it is in, say, [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection API allows one to manipulate/access data that is not accessable otherwise - or some data on the class that is unknown at compile time.

In here, it is really not needed. All you need is to `put()` the element into the map, it will "remove" the old value from the key you just inserted (if it is already there) and associate it (the key) with the newly added value.

So, basically - all you need to do is `myMap.put(key,newValue)`, and the implementation of the `Map` (assuming it is a correct one, of course) will take care of the rest.

---

If you want to store the data between runs of the program - you will have to save it (the map) on disk. In order to do so, you can use [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java), or if you can use  [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) in some cases.

Make sure that you load the map from disk once the program starts, or you will not see the values you stored.

Comment: But then as soon as my program exits this new value that I have inserted with put() method is lost !!

Comment: So you DO want to store it? Your comments made it unclear, let me edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just say, `mymap.put(key,value);`. It will update the value for matching key. If not there, it will insert a new entry e.g.

```
      mymap.put("Hello",4);
```

If you don't want to insert new value for a new key e.g. `World`, you can put a check like this:

```
      if(mymap.containsKey(key)){
         mymap.put(key,value);
      }else{
        //no existing key found
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Preferences API makes it easy to store a small amount of data on disk. It's usually used to store configuration data. It's similar to the Windows registry.

Here's an introduction: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html